# Problem with the parameter inside function in DOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I just watch a demonstration video with the code below. There is one thing really confused me that is at the bottom of the javascript, he put a parameter `item` inside the function. What does it refers to? And, so I do not know why he has to put firstChild here `var itemName = item.firstChild.textContent;`. And this line `if(itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1` is difficult for me to understand, cause `itemName` and `text` are two separate items but the comparison is done within one line of code. I would appreciate it if you could help, thank you.

```
var form = document.getElementById('addForm');
var itemList = document.getElementById('items');
var filter = document.getElementById('filter');

// Form submit event
form.addEventListener('submit', addItem);
// Delete event
itemList.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
// Filter event
filter.addEventListener('keyup', filterItems);

// Add item
function addItem(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Get input value
  var newItem = document.getElementById('item').value;

  // Create new li element
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  // Add class
  li.className = 'list-group-item';
  // Add text node with input value
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newItem));

  // Create del button element
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

  // Add classes to del button
  deleteBtn.className = 'btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete';

  // Append text node
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('X'));

  // Append button to li
  li.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  // Append li to list
  itemList.appendChild(li);
}

// Remove item
function removeItem(e){
  if(e.target.classList.contains('delete')){
    if(confirm('Are You Sure?')){
      var li = e.target.parentElement;
      itemList.removeChild(li);
    }
  }
}

// Filter Items
function filterItems(e){
  // convert text to lowercase
  var text = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  // Get lis
  var items = itemList.getElementsByTagName('li');
  // Convert to an array
  Array.from(items).forEach(function(item){
    var itemName = item.firstChild.textContent;
    if(itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1){
      item.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
```

```
<header id="main-header" class="bg-success text-white p-4 mb-3">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h1 id="header-title">Item Lister</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" placeholder="Search Items...">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="main" class="card card-body">
    <h2 class="title">Add Items</h2>
    <form id="addForm" class="form-inline mb-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="item">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2 class="title">Items</h2>
    <ul id="items" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 1 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 2 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 3 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Item 4 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete">X</button></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: textContent uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster ,it use to fecth text inside the html tag or element

Comment: Are you referring to `Array.from(items).forEach(function(item){`? Well that specifies the name of the parameter for the callback function, so that the current array element can be accessed via that name inside.

Comment: Thank you All. I will look into callback function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**textContent uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster ,it use to fecth text inside the html tag or element**

`if(itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1){`  here text is string that we are searching in itemName,if itemName contain text, indexof will not return -1,else it will retrun -1

simple word if its found string that text hold in itemName then if condition `if(itemName.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) != -1)` return true